# Trigger event when WebBrowser text selection changed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, textselection

Two parts of my program are a winforms `WebBrowser` and a simple `TextBox`.

What I want now is, when I select a text in the `WebBrowser` it automatically copies the selected text in the `TextBox`.

I could not find anything about this on google so I'd be glad if someone could help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach an event handler to [`onselectionchange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536968(v=vs.85).aspx) event of [`Document`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `WebBrowser` control using [`AttachEventHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.attacheventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) method of document. Then you can use properties of [`DomDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.domdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) to get selected text.

**Example**

```
void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) 
{
    webBrowser1.Document.AttachEventHandler("onselectionchange", selectionchange);
}
private void selectionchange(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    dynamic document = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
    dynamic selection = document.selection;
    dynamic text = selection.createRange().text;
    this.textBox1.Text= (string)text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but this need a trigger example a button click for the value to be passed on your TextBox1. Unfortunately, mouse event is not supported on WebBrowser control.

```
 dynamic document = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
 dynamic selection = document.selection;
 dynamic text = selection.createRange().text;
 TextBox1.Text = text;
```

Comment: I have read that in other posts already, but how do i know when something is selected? i can't just run this method without getting an information that the selection changed

Comment: Mouse event is unfortunately not supported in WebBrowser control @MartinNiederl

Comment: i know and that's the reason why i asked this question, because there will be a way how to do this :D